# Why does this still have a poisson distribution?

Tags: poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Definition given:
A stochastic process $\{X(t),t\geq 0\}$ is a compound Poisson process (used for modelling aggregate claim size) if:
$$X(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{N(t)} Y_i$$
for $t\geq 0$ and where
$\{N(t),t\geq 0\}$ is a Poisson process (number of claims/frequency of claims)
$\{Y_i,i=1,2,\ldots,n\}$ are iid random variables (not necessarily Poisson) and are the claim sizes.

Since $X(t)$ will follow Poisson distribution, why does adding non Poisson iid r.v.s $Y_i$ give a Poisson random variable? Does it have something to do with the fact that the **number** of claims are Poisson distributed?

Comment: "Since X(t) will follow poisson distribution" Huh? Who says it will?

Answer (score 3):

$X(t)$ need not be a Poisson process. For example, if $Y_i\equiv 2$, then $X(t)=2N(t)$ is not a Poisson process.

Comment: Is the definition inconsistent then? It's calling $X(t)$ a "compound Poisson process".

Comment: I guess a compound Poisson process need not be a Poisson process. It is probably the other way around. A Poisson process is a special case of a compound Poisson process.

Comment: I see; maybe my conclusion that a compound Poisson process would have poisson distribution, since the poisson process is poisson distributed is incorrect.

Comment: @Ron Correct guess.